# awk to Count Sum and Unique improve command - Con:

Tags: awk

Would like to print based on 2nd column & 4th column ,count of line items, sum of 3rd column and unique values of first column

Input.csv

```
abc,xx,5,Jan-2014
abc,yy,10,Jan-2014
def,xx,15,Jan-2014
def,yy,20,Jan-2014
abc,xx,5,Jan-2014
abc,yy,10,Jan-2014
def,xx,15,Jan-2014
def,yy,20,Jan-2014
ghi,zz,10,Jan-2014
abc,xx,5,Feb-2014
abc,yy,10,Feb-2014
def,xx,15,Feb-2014
def,yy,20,Feb-2014
abc,xx,5,Feb-2014
abc,yy,10,Feb-2014
def,xx,15,Feb-2014
def,yy,20,Feb-2014
ghi,zz,10,Feb-2014
```

Attempt#1:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
{ keys=$2","$4;keys[$2][$4]++;  sum[$2]+=$3 } !seen[$1,$2,$4]++ { count[$2]++ }
END   { for(key in keys) print key, keys[key], sum[key], count[key] }
' Input.csv
```

Attempt#2:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
{ keys=[$2][$4];keys[$2][$4]++;  sum[$2]+=$3 } !seen[$1,$2,$4]++ { count[$2]++ }
END   { for(key in keys) print key, keys[key], sum[key], count[key] }
' Input.csv
```

Attempt#3:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
{ keys=[$2,$4];keys[$2][$4]++;  sum[$2]+=$3 } !seen[$1,$2,$4]++ { count[$2]++ }
END   { for(key in keys) print key, keys[key], sum[key], count[key] }
' Input.csv
```

Desired Output:

```
xx,Jan-2014,4,40,2
yy,Jan-2014,4,60,2
zz,Jan-2014,1,10,1
xx,Feb-2014,4,40,2
yy,Feb-2014,4,60,2
zz,Feb-2014,1,10,1
```

Looking for your suggestions !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order of output is critical then you can do:

```
awk '
BEGIN { SUBSEP = FS = OFS = "," }
!seen[$1,$2,$4]++ { count[$2,$4]++ } 
!patt[$2,$4]++    { order[++nr] = $2 FS $4 }
{ values[$2,$4]++; sum[$2,$4]+=$3 } 
END { 
    for (idx=1; idx<=nr; idx++) 
        print order[idx], values[order[idx]], sum[order[idx]], count[order[idx]] 
}' file 
xx,Jan-2014,4,40,2
yy,Jan-2014,4,60,2
zz,Jan-2014,1,10,1
xx,Feb-2014,4,40,2
yy,Feb-2014,4,60,2
zz,Feb-2014,1,10,1
```

We set the Input and Output field separator to `,`. `SUBSEP` is set to `,` to prevent using `,` as a key separator for arrays. `!seen[$1,$2,$4]++` remembers the pattern based on 3 columns specified and keeps a counter. `!patt[$2,$4]++` helps us to remember the order. `values[$2,$4]++` and `sum[$2,$4]+=$3` keeps track of the count of unique patterns based on second and forth column and the sum of it respectively.

In the `END` block we iterate over our order and print the output from these arrays.

**Note:** As suggested in the comments, looking at your attempts of using `a[$1,$2]` and `a[$1][$2]`, you should be aware that they are completely different. `a[$1,$2]` an array of strings indexed by `1 SUBSEP 2` where as `a[1][2]` is an array indexed by 1 of arrays indexed by 2. The second is GNU `awk` only.

Comment: @EdMorton Yea good suggestion. Using composite keys separated by `SUBSEP` always got the job done for me so I have never really used the true multi-dimensional arrays in `awk`. I think I should start reading about it. `:)`

Comment: 2-D arrays are very useful for many common applications. An application like reading vals for a common key on multiple lines with a pseudo-2d array: `a[$1] = ($1 in a ? a[$1] RS : "") $2;...END{for (key in a) { split(a[key],tmp,RS); for (i=1;i in tmp; i++) { val=tmp[i]; print key, val } } }` becomes much simpler with a true-2d array: `a[$1][$2];...END{for (key in a) for (val in a[key]) print key, val}`. There may be a syntax error or 2 in there but you get the idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60716/discussion-between-avn-and-jaypal).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
awk '{i=$2 FS $4; S[i]+=$3} !A[$1,i]++{C[i]++} END{for(i in S) print i, S[i], C[i]}' FS=, OFS=, file
```

Multiline:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
  }

  {
    idx=$2 FS $4
    Sum[idx]+=$3
  }

  !Seen[$1,idx]++ {
    Count[idx]++
  }

  END {
    for(idx in Sum) print idx, Sum[idx], Count[idx]
  }
' file
```

Output:

```
xx,Feb-2014,40,2
zz,Feb-2014,10,1
yy,Feb-2014,60,2
yy,Jan-2014,60,2
xx,Jan-2014,40,2
zz,Jan-2014,10,1
```